# IPHONE: After Removing / Adding Subviews in the App Delegate, Orientation Changes Fail

Tags: iphone, interface, ipad, orientation, rotation

I am using my application delegate to swap out views. First I remove the current view, then I add the new view, then I run a quartz animation.

No matter what view I load first, the orientation changes occur as expected. As soon as I start adding new views (removing the old) to the window in the application delegate, orientation changes no longer happen. Assume shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is present with YES in all my UIViewControllers.

I took out the quartz animation and here is where I am still stuck:

```
-(void) showSongList {
  [songVC.view removeFromSuperView];
  navVC = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:0 bundle:0];
  [window addSubView:navVC.view];
  [songVC release];
  songVC = nil;
}
```

Switch views works fine. The first view always responds and switches orientation, then any changes I make to the window adding views (always removing the previous), diminishes the orientation changes.

If I load navVC right away it will rotate orientation, but when it's further down the line from a button event, I get the orientation problem I've described.

NSLog(@"subview count = %d", [[window subviews] count]); //always 1

I have tried using NSLog in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation and this function obviously is only called when an orientation change occurs.

My app delegate window always only has one subview, so I'm lost!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured out what to do ... I created a UIViewController called SwapViewController and added my other views to that.

I thought that this didn't work, when I first tried because I went straight ahead and added a UIView programmatically. But I guess, given UIViewController has the orientation functions, a view controller was required.

So, make one swap view controller and add subviews to that!